# What is the process for Unidirectional Data Flow in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Please suggest me,If there any example for Unidirectional Data Flow in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this video: [Unidirectional Data Flow in Swift: An Alternative to Massive View Controllers](https://realm.io/news/benji-encz-unidirectional-data-flow-swift/). Speaker talks about Swift projects and Flux architecture, but in my opinion you can understand base principles of Unidirectional Data Flow, because it's not related to Objective-C only.